Is this a constrained list question?
'Hidden' non white characters in Heinleins work. So racists would identify with them before learning their race
I currently have a kneejerk vote in that this is a "list or recommendation" question, but with a second look, I'm wondering if maybe this is reasonably constrained and answerable. Not really an opinion question either, since it's pretty clear-cut whether someone's race doesn't have indications until the end, although we really can't speculate that much on Heinlein's intent in most cases.

Technically it's a constrained list, since Heinlein's oeuvre is not going to grow.  My problem with some of the "not an unconstrained list" decisions is when it's a fixed but large list.  Heinlein published over 100 works (not counting variants and translations), so the odds are we'll end up with about a dozen answers each mentioning a single work, avoiding which is the intent of the "list or recommendation" close reason.

It's also a really opinion-y kind of question. What defines a 'hidden character'. Are we going to count everyone whose race isn't mentioned until after their first line?

Also, is that even what Heinlein was going for in Starship Troopers? Could it just be that there were other earlier mentions of Johnny's race that got edited out, or did he perhaps just think that a surname like Rico was already pretty on-the-nose?

@Valorum also, not that it matters much since the movie is intentionally divergent, but Verhoeven's Rico is obviously not ethnically Filipino nor "from Buenos Aires" (I am from Buenos Aires, by the way!). Who knows what Heinlein intended? I agree it's likely opinion based.

@AndresF. - Rico isn't a prototypical  'white' surname. I assume he was Latino (or had Latino heritage) right from the first time I saw his name. Also, aren't Latino people classed as white/caucasian (even if they're a bit olive-skinned)

@Valorum: It can go either way.

@Valorum it gets complicated... "latino" is an identity at this point more than anything else. There are Latinos with Spanish ancestry, with Amerindian heritage, African/mulatto (depending on which country), some with misc European ancestry (myself, Italians are common in Buenos Aires). "Rico" is not at all a common surname here, in fact I never heard it. While some people here look like Casper van Diem (I am light haired with grey/blue eyes, but I don't look nothing like him), I would guess he definitely doesn't look Filipino!

Rico seems to be more of a name than a surname (derived from Italian "Enrico"), though Wikipedia lists either as possible, with name being the far more common choice. I have never heard of either in Argentina. To be honest, to me this seems to be Heinlein randomly trying a name that sounded vaguely latino to him, as if I tried to create an (US) American name and chose "Johnny McJohns".

On reflection, I think I voted to close this question for the wrong reason. You're absolutely right that it's a finite list, since Heinlein's body of works isn't growing any more after his death, with the exception of a few posthumous trifles that came out in the 1980s and 1990s. My initial objection is that his body of works is simply so large ("32 novels, 59 short stories, and 16 collections") that we're going to end up with a bunch of me too, me three answers, each offering one or two possible examples. While that's not necessarily a bad thing, it certainly isn't the sort of thing that we're usually about.

All of the above being said, I still believe that this question is a bad fit for the site. The original poster hasn't properly defined what a 'hidden non-white character' actually is, and any answer is just going to be based on the answerer's own opinion of what that looks like.
I, for example, disagree with the most prominent example. I always assumed that someone with a surname like 'Rico' was almost certainly going to be Hispanic and so his identity being revealed as Filipino was in no way surprising to me.

You're not wrong about any of the substantive points, but while "Rico" is a Latin-derived surname, I initially assumed it was South American.  (That is, it didn't speak "Filipino" to me.)  I understand it now, but when I first read the book I was thinking of the wrong immigrant group, and in my experience people don't think of, say, Argentinians as being "non-white."  (Argentinian in particular because Rico's mom was killed in Buenos Aires.)

@DavidW - Maybe because I'm not American, but I don't really distinguish between various flavours of Latino in South American. If memory serves he doesn't actually say he's Fillipino, just that he was born/grew up there or speak the lingo. This wasn't a shocking revelation to me, more of a huh?

Filipinos are not considered latinos and the average Filipino looks nothing like the average Argentinian (I am Argentinian). Casper van Dien doesn't look like either, of course, but Verhoeven was going for parody :) I think indeed this question is a bad fit for the site (and may devolve in ugly arguments, too)
